# Add columns in result of if

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have two sheets. The first contains 4 columns and the second contains a column with cells that each can take values from the first column of the first sheet.

So e.g.
Sheet 1:

```
    A  B  C  D
1   A1 B1 C1 D1
2   A2 B2 C2 D2
3   ...
```

Sheet 2:

```
     A                                     B
  1  can contain Sheet1.A1-Sheet1.AXX      Sheet1.D1-Sheet1.DXX
  2  ...
```

My question now is how can I have column B contain corresponding entry to the choice in column A. So when I choose Sheet1.A20 in Sheet2.A1 for example, then Sheet2.B1 should contain Sheet1.D20.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does Sheet2.A1 contain the literal text 'Sheet1.A20' or a reference to Sheet1.A20?

In the first case: Use text functions to examine the text in Sheet2.A1 and extract the reference, then refer to the cell you want using [INDIRECT](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#INDIRECT)

In the second case: Use [VLOOKUP](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#VLOOKUP) to find the value of Sheet2.A1 in Sheet1's A column and get the corresponding B column value.